# aws route traffic for corporate network to other vpc

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

is it in any way possible to get the trafic for a corporate network routed to another VPC, which will forward it in turn to the network itself?

I see my ICMP requests arriving on my most-distant machine, and it sends a reply that never arrives.

I've configured a route that sends all traffic for my corporate network to the peering connection, but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

EDIT: Clarification:
Most-distant is in VPC-2, which is peered bi-directional to VPC-1, which is the VPN-entry point.
I'm trying to ping from corporate to most-distant.

Routing tables on the VPC's have been configured to have the traffic to corporate to go to either peering connection when in VPC2, or to VPN-interface when in VPC1.

The VPN is not in NAT mode

Comment: You have a VPN connection into VPC A.  VPC B is "another VPC" that uses VPC peering to connect to VPC A.  Correct so far?  If so, tell us where that "most distant" machine is in this network and where you're pinging it from.  Also, where did you add this route?  The VPN connection itself has no route table, does it? Route tables are associated with subnets, determining where instance-initiated traffic routes to.

Comment: added clarification

Comment: Thanks.  Now... you say a ping from corporate is actually transiting VPC A and received on a machine in VPC B, but the response packet does not make it back?  Can you verify this again?

Comment: i used tcpdump to check if pings were arriving, and diagnose sniffer packet any "icmp" on fortigate instance to see if they were passing by. REQ was sent, RESP never arrived back in VPC1, nor corporate network

Answer (score 0):

If i read your configuration correctly. No. [You provided an example specifically stated in the invalid configuration - transitive peering section of the AWS docs themselves](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/PeeringGuide/invalid-peering-configurations.html)